# How VoIP handles datagrams that arrive late?

Tags: udp, voip

I know that VoIP uses UDP for the transport layer which doesn't ensure ordered delivery. Whenever I use VoIP phone, some times I experience lost sentences and blurred sentences. However, I never hear an older sentence arriving after a new sentence. How does VoIP manage to do this?

Thanks in advance,
Pavan.

Comment: How does it know that it has arrived late? There is no sequence number or timestamp on the datagram.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on implementation. RTP combined with SIP might be common protocol set used and RTP packets have timestamps. RTP packet receiver has usually something called jitter buffer that is delaying playback a little (~100ms range) and is managing list of already received packets (capacity of few packets). Packets that arrived slightly out of order can be inserted in the middle of this list thus playback order can be restored.

Regardless of this hearing audio in reversed order would be very unlikely. Each packet holds only about 20 ms of audio so even if some dumb implementation would ignore timestamps and/or wouldn't be able to restore order you wouldn't hear this as sentence reorder but rather serious audio distortions. Used compression may also be important as codec may not be able to recover quickly if it receives packets in wrong order.